Why does not Earth radiate more energy into the space while it gets warmer?
The earth is getting warmer. By Stephan's law, it should radiate more energy into the universe.
On the other hand, the energy from the sun is a constant. So how to achieve a balance?

Search term: "radiation balance."

On the outside it is getting colder, on the inside it is getting warmer.

It is radiating more energy as it gets warmer, that's why a higher amount of carbon dioxide can be linked with a fixed higher temperature (in the equilibrum), and not with an ongoing temperature increase.

This question is similar to: Global warming and planetary thermodynamics. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The Stefan-Boltzmann law gives only emitted energy. Energy balance involves also reflected energy, not just emitted energy. So it is possible that balance changes in the sense the Earth emits more, but reflects less than before, so net energy leaving can remain about the same, equal to the energy coming towards the Earth from the Sun.

It is a duplication of the first related question but good answers deserve repeating...
In fact, it's the other way around: the Earth is warming because it's radiating less energy.
The thermal radiation is emitted from the surface, but is reflected by greenhouse gases, so it doesn't reach space.
Equilibrium will be reached when the Earth is warm enough to radiate as much energy as it receives from the Sun, even after all these filters. But this equilibrium may be a little uncomfortable for human beings.
That's why the current strategy is to reduce the amount of greenhouse gases in the atmosphere to allow the Earth to radiate more.
BTW, there is one problem with this strategy: as soon as the temperature of the atmosphere anywhere reach the point of sublimation of CO2 (-78°C) the process of "getting rid of greenhouse gases" may become an avalanche and the Earth will be converted into another Mars in no time. The current temperature record is -91°C and I have no idea why we are still alive.

"I have no idea why we are still alive" - a small portion of Earth being briefly cool enough to solidify carbon dioxide may set up a positive feedback, but that feedback won't cause arbitrarily large cooling, especially with all the other factors at work, such as the limited airflow between Antarctica and the rest of Earth, the warming effect such airflow has on Antarctica, and a subsequent increase in Antarctic sunlight.

The sublimation point of CO2 is pressure dependent, so the sublimation temperature will be lower at altitude.

Snowball Earth

I believe the sublimation point depends on the partial pressure of the gas under consideration, not the total pressure of whatever mixture of gases is invovled. The partial pressure of CO2 will be on the order of 10^-3 atmospheres, giving a sublimation point of below -120° C.

The biggest greenhouse gas is not CO2, it's water vapor, by a factor of 2-3. Earth regularly reaches temperatures where water freezes.

If this question is already answered well, it is a duplicate. It does not require a repeated answer, it needs closing and direction to the good answers that exist sleeady

Source on "it's radiating less energy"? Gases do not just reflect IR radiation, they also absorb it, and this should increase average temperature at lower heights of the atmosphere. If temperature of surface and densest parts of atmosphere increases, then net emission should increase.

The (surface of the) Earth is radiating more as it gets warmer, but only some of it escapes into "the universe". The rest is absorbed in the atmosphere and then about half of that is re-radiated back towards the Earth.
Another way of looking at this is that the total amount of radiation emitted from the Earth as a whole (from the top of the atmosphere) is more or less constant, as is the "effective temperature". Greenhouse gases shift the height from which radiation escapes at this effective temperature upwards, and since the adiabatic lapse rate (the atmospheric temperature gradient) is also more or less fixed, the surface temperature must increase.
In fact, because the Earth is not exactly in equilibrium, or more specifically, the oceans are getting warmer, there is a small flux imbalance such that the Earth as a whole radiates less into space than it receives from the Sun, by about 0.3% and growing. Read for example here.

Do you mean net outgoing energy from the Earth (including the reflected energy) is the same, or only net thermal emission is the same? Opacity to IR increases, so  thermal emission from layers of atmosphere with the same or higher temperature should increase.

@JánLalinský the Earth is in equilibrium. To first order, increasing greenhouse gases do not change how much solar energy impacts, is reflected or is absorbed by the Earth. Therefore the net luminosity of radiation from the Earth into space is unchanged. What changes is the height from which that radiation escapes and the surface temperature of the Earth.

Can you explain why there should be no change in net thermal emission? I think the opposite should be true: emission should increase. If atmosphere is getting new gas particles and temperature of troposphere at the level of sea is increasing, then over a long time, the atmosphere is slowly expanding, and the IR-opaque part, thermally emiting energy to space, is growing. Even if effective temperature of the boundary with space remained the same (which I also do not understand, it should increase), net emission would be increasing.

If you go out in the cold without a coat your outside is warm and you cool off fast. If you go out with a coat your outside, that is the surface of the coat, is cold and you stay warm inside.
With Earth it works the same way. More CO$_2$ means a colder top of the atmosphere and a higher surface temperature.
Note that this analogy is not intended as a thermal model of Earth. I hope nobody interpreted it as such! It is intended to show that Earth getting warmer on the inside does not imply that it is also warmer on the outside.

The "luminosity" of someone wearing a coat is lower. The luminosity of the Earth is (roughly) constant.

This situation is not really comparable to earth, though, is it? A human body produces a significant amount of heat compared to how much it radiates away, while earth does not. Earth receives most of its heat from outside, which a coat would suppress. In fact, a coat would keep earth cooler because if it prevents radiation from leaving, then it also prevents it from arriving.

@Vercassivelaunos A CO2 coat does not suppress light coming in. It keeps heat radiation in.

@my2cts Yes, but humans wear mostly coats from fibers. The differences between a greenhouse gas coat around earth and a wool coat around a human are relevant in explaining the physics. A snowman with a wool coat melts slower than a naked one. Which is why I don't think it's a good analogy - at least without highlighting the relevant differences.

@Vercassivelaunos I agree the comparing a person with a coat and Earth with CO2 in its atmosphere has limitations. However, replacing the person with a snowman is completely inadequate. Earth is heated by optical and UV light. Thus converted ultimately into heat. A person also produces heat. A snowman does not produce heat. By the way, a snowman would only melt at T>0K. The environment of Earth in space is on average much colder than that.

‘ The differences between a greenhouse gas coat around earth and a wool coat around a human are relevant in explaining the physics. ’ Actually, not very much  so for the basic physics, excrpt that coats are not optically transparent. The sky is not a fur coat, I’ll give you that.

But the fact that CO2 is optically transparent (and reflective in the infrared) is the entire reason that it works the way it does. If we wrapped earth in a huge coat of a similar reflectivity as earth's surface, then earth's surface temperature would not change at all in the equilibrium state (it would just take longer to reach equilibrium). Greenhouse gases on the other hand do change the equilibrium temperature at earth's surface. That's a significant difference if you ask me.

Coat prevents energy losses via conduction, not energy losses via radiation. A reflective blanket would be a better analogy.

The simple answer is: the radiation balance occurs at 1 optical depth (in the IR--not the visible). As the atmosphere changes, we down on the surface are optically deeper (in the IR), and hence, warmer.

Stefan's law only applies to black bodies. Earth is not black. It can reflect radiation. Greenhouse gases specifically reflect much infrared radiation, but less of the radiation coming from the sun, which is mostly in the visible spectrum. An object which reflects infrared will only weakly emit infrared. But most of the thermal radiation at earth's temperature is infrared. If we suppress earth's ability to absorb and thus emit infrared, earth has to be hotter in order to emit the same intensity radiation as before.
But would reduced absorption not also mean less power reaching earth? True, but only from the infrared spectrum. And the sun radiates mostly in the visible spectrum. If earth keeps absorbing that, it receives the same amount of energy, but can emit less of it at its current temperature, and will thus warm up.
